# PostGIS error reads "Geometry has Z dimension but column does not"

Tags: postgis, postgresql, geojson, error, dimensions

I try to store a polygon in GeoJSON format into my PostGIS table. Both are using the CRS `EPSG:3857`. This is how the polygon is defined. Note that I put in some whitespace to make it more readable.

```
{
    "type":"Polygon",
    "coordinates":[
        [-91.23046875,45.460130637921],
        [-79.8046875,49.837982453085],
        [-69.08203125,43.452918893555],
        [-88.2421875,32.694865977875],
        [-91.23046875,45.460130637921]
    ],
    "crs":{"type":"name","properties":{"name":"EPSG:3857"}}
}
```

To store that in my database I use the following SQL query.

```
INSERT INTO tablename (name, polygon)
VALUES ('name', ST_GeomFromGeoJSON('GeoJSON string comes here...'))
```

But for some reason the above query throws an error.

```
ERROR:  Geometry has Z dimension but column does not
```

What is wrong in my attempt?

Comment: It seems to me that the problem is in your table, probably you have a z column in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution. The GeoJSON specification says that the coordinates of a polygon are *an array* of line strings. Therefore I had to wrap them with additional brackets.

```
{
    "type":"Polygon",
    "coordinates":
    [
        [
            [-91.23046875,45.460130637921],
            [-79.8046875,49.837982453085],
            [-69.08203125,43.452918893555],
            [-88.2421875,32.694865977875],
            [-91.23046875,45.460130637921]
        ]
    ],
    "crs":{"type":"name","properties":{"name":"EPSG:3857"}}
}
```

Comment: I have the same error, but i don't understand the solution..... Can explain pls ?